# run python unittest case strictly sequentially?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I would like to run the individual tests (functions) of my Python unittest Class in sequential order and not in parallel. I can tell it is parallel because the first function/test writes a record into the TinyDB and another function/test - which fails - needs to read that new record and make an existence test.

So, how do I enforce the strict sequential test execution?
If that is NOT possible, can I enforce the strict sequential processing in creating multiple tests? (I would dislike to do so, because I would like to have a 1:1 relationship of modules and their test_modules.)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for unittest**

A strict execution I could realize by creating a master test py file. Named it run_all_tests.py

The modules have separate classes. I trigger them one by one. Respectively the functions.

**Switching to pytest and fixtures**

Anyhow, I dislike that short-coming of controlling the sequence in a sophisticated/declarative way on a function level. Thus I switched to pytest.
First of all I like that there is an argument that shows the sequence. That confirms what we are expecting:

```
pytest -setup-show test_myfunction.py
```

On top of it, you may apply the decorator `@pytest.fixture()` to a method that is run before. This does NOT necessarily help us with the sequence in first line. Complementary, it reminds us of making independent tests - where one uses the `@pytest.fixture()` annotated method as an argument to the test function. This way one has a deliberate fixture for a single function. Do NOT mistaken that as the same as the `setUp()` method of unittest. They run before every single method. Every. And the `setUpClass()` runs once before any test function is invoked.

For those who still want declarative order, you find it here: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/, https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-order